# How to use ui:insert in Primefaces p:tabMenu

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a bro problem which I don't know how to solve. I have this Primefaces `p:tabMenu` which is used to call tabs with lazy loading.

```
<p:tabMenu id="tabs" activeIndex="0" > 
    <p:menuitem value="tab1" url="/tab1.jsf" /> 
    <p:menuitem value="tab2" url="/tab2.jsf" /> 

</p:tabMenu>
```

I want to use the JSF tag `ui:insert` in order to call the tab's code. How I can combine the `ui:insert` tag into the above code?

Comment: What do you mean by cal the tab's code?

Comment: You should look into how to use a [templating with Facelets](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-templating-with-facelets-example/).  You can have all of your tab.jsf files extend the main template that contains the tabMenu.

Comment: Could you please show me how I can use `ui:insert` into `p:tabMenu`?

Comment: @user1285928 why don't you use `src=` value of `<ui:include` in `url=` attribute of `<p:menuitem` ?

Comment: Would you write a short example of your idea?

Comment: Hi @user1285928, in this case in does not make sense to use ui:insert. you can just have 2 pages: tab1.jsf and tab2.jsf. each of these pages, at the top, has the snippet code you posted, with the tabMenu.
instead, if you use tabView then you can use ui:insert. that way both tabs will be in the same page. what approach do you prefer? if you want I can elaborate on the tabView approach with ui:insert

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I see 2 approaches here:

1) Use one page for each tab. use the p:tabMenu component (available in primefaces 3.4).  In this case, if user is viewing one tab and clicks on the second tab to display it, he will be redirected to another page. 
**pros**: if you want to navigate from another page to the second tab, it's easy since it's a different page (see cons in 2nd approach). also, each tab page is load fast because it only contains code for one tab. you'll have a better separation of code.
**cons**: if users goes to another tab, all data entered in current tab will be lost. also, changing from one tab to another is not so fast because there is navigation involved.

this is the page for one tab (tab1.xhtml):

```
<h:body>
    <p:tabMenu activeIndex="0">  
        <p:menuitem value="Tab 1" url="/tab1.jsf" />  
        <p:menuitem value="Tab 2" url="/tab2.jsf" />  
    </p:tabMenu>
    <!-- content of tab1 goes here -->
</h:body>
```

this is the code for the other tab (tab2.xhtml):

```
<h:body>
    <p:tabMenu activeIndex="1">  
        <p:menuitem value="Tab 1" url="/tab1.jsf" />  
        <p:menuitem value="Tab 2" url="/tab2.jsf" />  
    </p:tabMenu>
    <!-- content of tab2 goes here -->
</h:body>
```

2) The other approach is to have one page with p:tabView. in this case, all the tab contents go in the same page. you can use dynamic="true" attribute on p:tabView to render the tab contents on demand and accelerate page load.
**pros**: smoother transition from tab to tab (always stays on same page).
**cons**: if you want to navigate directly to the 2nd tab for example, it's not so easy. so will have to use activeIndex attribute of tabView pointing to an attribute in the managed bean that handles the first tab, and still you'll be constructing the bean of the first tab when you actually don't need it.

this is the code for the main page that contains the tab:

```
<h:body>
    <p:tabView dynamic="true">
        <p:tab id="tab1" title="Tab 1" >
            <ui:include src="tab2.xhtml" />
        </p:tabView>
        <p:tab id="tab2" title="Tab 2" >
            <ui:include src="tab2.xhtml" />
        </p:tab>
    </p:tabView>
</h:body>
```

and you'll need the pages for each tab (that is inserted into main page):
tab1.xhtml:

tab2.xhtml:

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want to share code between tabs?

I think you are staring yourself blind on the tabMenu component. You do not need it's assistance to properly use templates here.

Just:

1. Define a template
2. Have pages use that template

Those pages could then be tabs or whatever you want.

a proper structure could perhaps be to define tabs.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
          "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions"
    xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui">


<h:head>
    <h:outputStylesheet name="style.css" library="css" />
    <div id="header">

        <ui:insert name="header">
            <title><ui:insert name="title">title</ui:insert></title>

        </ui:insert>
    </div>

</h:head>

<h:body>
    <div id="content">

        <ui:insert name="content">
        content here
        </ui:insert>
    </div>

</h:body>

</html>
```

Then for each tab you have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:of="http://omnifaces.org/functions"
    xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions"
    template="/WEB-INF/templates/template.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="header">
    a specific tab header here
    </ui:define>
    <ui:define name="content">
    specific content here
    </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
```

Note that this is just standard templating with JSF 2. Good luck

Comment: Yes. JSF template is something very simple. But again how I can mix `p:tabMenu` with template?

Comment: Look at my example above. Each tab in p:tabMenu is a page written with ui:composition.

<p:menuitem value="tab1" url="/tab1.jsf" /> That could be a templated page.


If you are not satisified with this answer you most give a proper example of what you want to do. Write it in pseudo code or something